# JSF 2.0: data not updated before the view is rendered

Tags: java, jsf-2, updates

In my application, I have the following beans:

```
@Named(value = "mrBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MrBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private MrsBean mrsBean;

    private Item item;

    public void updateItem() {
        this.item = mrsBean.updateItem(item.getId());
    }

}

@Named(value = "itemBean")
@RequestScoped
public class itemBean {
    @Inject
    private MrBean mrBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("update") != null) mrBean.updateItem();
    }
}
```

Before showing the item's information on the `ViewItem.xhtml` page, I will check if the `update` parameter is submitted to update the item before showing.

When I test the page with the parameter `update=true`, I have no idea why the old data was rendered instead of the new updated one. In fact, I have to refresh the page before the new data is rendered.

From the above result, I wonder if the `@PostConstruct` method was called after the view was rendered.

I'd be very grateful if you could give me an advice.

Best regards,

Comment: Just as a question, but why don't you invoke the update logic inside a method referenced in a f:event with preRenderView inside a f:metadata tag to update the item in ViewItem.xhtml? Does (or will) itemBean have any other responsibility?

Comment: I guess you have in your xhtml some input with `value=#{mrBean.item}`, right? And your problem is that it is not the right value when the `@PostConstruct` method itemBean.init() executes?

Comment: @eljunior: the method `init()` would update the item with the latest data. In my case, the page still show the old data until I refresh the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can happen if `#{itemBean}` is been referenced for the first time in the view *after* `#{mrBean.item}`. E.g.

```
#{mrBean.item}
...
#{itemBean}
```

The managed beans are constructed for the first time when an EL expression references it for the first time and it does not exist in the scope yet. On a GET request wherein the managed bean instance is not referenced by a taghandler attribute or a `f:event`, then it would only be constructed during the render response.

If rearranging them so that the `#{itemBean}` is always referenced (and thus constructed) *before* `#{mrBean.item}` is been referenced is not possible, then better make the `@PostConstruct` of `#{itemBean}` a `<f:event type="preRenderView">` instead.

```html
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{itemBean.init}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting another solution just in case it helps you. You can try a different approach by invoking an initialization method each time the page is going to be rendered and avoid having a request bean to do the update. Add this metadata tag to your xhtml:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{mrBean.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

And in your MrBean, define this method:

```
public void init() {
    if(!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback() && FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("update") != null) 
        mrBean.updateItem();
}
```

This way, the updateItem check will be done every time the ViewItem page is rendered. If your MrBean was ViewScoped instead of SessionScoped I would have suggested to use a `@PostConstruct` annotation instead.

Comment: I have already thought of this solution. However, the problem with `preRenderView` event is that it would also execute on AJAX requests. In the future, I may need to change the `itemBean` into `@ViewScoped` and I think a `@PostConstruct` method would be neater.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes to avoid executing on AJAX requests, maybe you can just use an `if(!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) { // do your stuff }` in the `preRenderView`listener

Comment: I'd go for the viewscoped approach, but indeed, the isPostback should solve that. I've edited my answer.